# How to check if API key of Elastic Email API is correct or incorrect in asp.net and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, mailer

I am using Elastic Email API in my web application project in asp.net c#.
when I give `USERNAME` and `API_KEY` with other required data, email is sent to destination (I am sending email to myself for testing). And on receiving mail, there is one `Lable` on my page `"Mail is sent successfully"`

Now the problem is, if I provide wrong `USERNAME` and `API_KEY`, I will get `Lable` but not mail. I know because I have provided wrong `API_KEY`.

So how to check if i have provided valid `USERNAME` and `API_KEY` so that I can change Lable to `"check your data"`

My Code:

ElasticEmail.cs

```
public static string SaveAndTestElasticEmail(string from, string to, string fromName, string subject, string bodyHtml)
        {
            try
            {
                setElasticEmailSettings();
                string channel = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["registrationNumber"];
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                NameValueCollection values = new NameValueCollection();
                values.Add("username", USERNAME);
                values.Add("api_key", API_KEY);
                values.Add("from", from);
                values.Add("from_name", fromName);
                values.Add("subject", subject);
                values.Add("body_html", bodyHtml);
                values.Add("channel", channel);
                values.Add("to", to);
                byte[] response = client.UploadValues("https://api.elasticemail.com/mailer/send", values);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;

            }

        }
```

If I provide valid `API_KEY`and I debug my code, I am getting `response{[36]}` . and if I provide wrong key, then still I will receive response but it is, `response{[22]}` and I will not get mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
byte[] response = client.UploadValues("https://api.elasticemail.com/mailer/send", values);

if (response.Length <= 35)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```